# MPAndroidChart-BarChart issue

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I have some questions about BarChart.

Here is my chart data.

```
ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
xVals.add("AAA");
xVals.add("BBB");
xVals.add("Z1");
xVals.add("CCC");
xVals.add("DDD");
xVals.add("Z2");
xVals.add("EEE");
xVals.add("FFF");
xVals.add("Z3");
```

The BarChart data sets.

```
ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
ArrayList<BarEntry> yValsSet = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
yVals.add(new BarEntry(42, 0));
yVals.add(new BarEntry(15, 1));
yValsSet.add(new BarEntry(57, 2));
yVals.add(new BarEntry(35, 3));
yVals.add(new BarEntry(14, 4));
yValsSet.add(new BarEntry(49, 5));
yVals.add(new BarEntry(7, 6));
yVals.add(new BarEntry(21, 7));
yValsSet.add(new BarEntry(28, 8));
```

And the chart.
[image]

The "Z3" on x-axis didn't show.

And chart isn't at correct position.

The dark gray one is CCC's value, but it shows at Z1.

How to fix it?

---

UPDATE:
If I use only one data set, it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values that belong to each other (in terms of their x-axis label) must be on the same x-index.

Which means:

If you want to have the values 30 and 25 on the x-index with the description "AAA", you need to do the following:

```
ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
xVals.add("AAA");
xVals.add("BBB");
//... and so on

ArrayList<BarEntry> vals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
ArrayList<BarEntry> vals2 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

// this will be above "AAA"
vals1.add(new BarEntry(30, 0)); // use x-index 0 for both
vals2.add(new BarEntry(25, 0));

// this will be above "BBB"
vals1.add(new BarEntry(50, 1)); // use x-index 1 for both
vals2.add(new BarEntry(60, 1));
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to add a data to LineData, where some entries have same Xval(For eg Date). When I do this when same Date (xvals) coming, Dates are repeated in axis. Not plotting value under same xval. How to fix this ?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean, but I guess what you need is different datasets.

Comment: Can you tell me how to remove Xval when there is no entry ?

Comment: How to remove index if entry is null in mpandroidchart

Comment: In BarChart by-default all the bars are in horizontally, how to display it in vertically.??